# JSON Schema selector with free text

Tags: typescript, jsonschema

I'm using JSON Schema and I have a selection with enumeration.
But I wish that the user can write inside the selector if the value is not present.

```
{
  '$id': 'https://example.com/person.schema.json',
  '$schema': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#',
  title: '',
  type: 'object',
  required: [],
  properties: {
    Animals: {
      type: 'string',
      enum: [
        'fox',
        ' duck'
      ],
      title: 'Animals',
      span: 6
    }
  }
}
```

I wish that the user can be insert for instance `horse`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with JSON Schema. This is related to your frontend application. The purpose of JSON Schema is to validate data against the schema. If the user can modify thae schemas, that defeats the purpose of using a schema for validation.